# jquery ui datepicker dateFormat not working as expected

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have this line of code which calls the jquery ui datepicker, but it does not format the date as expected.

```
$('input.datepicker').datePicker({clickInput:true, dateFormat:'yyyy-mm-dd'});
```

I want the format to be yyyy-mm-dd, but once you choose a date from the jquery ui datepicker, it always populates the input field as mm/dd/yyyy. What the heck is up with this?

Comment: just as it's posted in the question, `.datePicker()`

Comment: I guess the template i'm working with is using this http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/ instead of jquery ui for the datepicker. Write that as an ansewr so I can accept it.

Comment: Did you solve it? Have you tried `altFormat`?

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you should use `dateFormat:'yy-mm-dd'`?

The documentation of the [dateFormat](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/formatDate) states that:

> yy - year (four digit)

Comment: Or make it explicit and use `$.datepicker.ISO_8601`.

Comment: @muistooshort i'm not familiar with this. What is it?

Comment: @Catfish: `$.datapicker.ISO_8601` is a constant that the jQuery-UI datepicker defines, see the documentation the matsev linked to.